# iOS App Using Carrierwave with Rails Backend

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have an iOS app with a Rails back-end. I use carrierwave with Amazon S3 to post images from a webpage to my server. I would like to be able to post images to the server from my iOS app, but am unsure of how to do this. I've made other requests by hitting certain endpoints with the correct parameters as displayed in the Rails console. However, I am unsure how to form this request:

```
Started POST "/images" for 173.22.40.246 at 2012-08-27 18:14:50 +0000
2012-08-27T18:14:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ImagesController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"1234", "image"=>{"name"=>"", "path"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000004e92830 @original_filename="image.jpeg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image[path]\"; filename=\"image.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20120827-2-1us2x41>>}, "commit"=>"Create Image"}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!